# Batch processing of numerous shapefiles in common folder with PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, shapefile, vector, batch

I am trying to batch process numerous shapefiles in a common folder.  I am getting an invalid syntax error right after the `processing.run` algorithm passes the `TARGET_CRS` words. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

```py
import processing
import glob
import os
import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

inpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/QGIS_Scripts_TESTING/QGIS_Reference_Data/Scrap/BATCH/shapefiles"
outpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/QGIS_Scripts_TESTING/QGIS_Reference_Data/Scrap/BATCH/reprojectedshapefiles"
   
os.chdir(inpath)
for layers in glob.glob(".shp"):
    processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {inpath,'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OPERATION':'+proj=noop',outpath})
```

I made some edits to the above script that seemed to resolve my original error, though I'm not able to generate an output.

```py
import processing
import glob
import os

inpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/QGIS_Scripts_TESTING/QGIS_Reference_Data/Scrap/BATCH/shapefiles"
outpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/QGIS_Scripts_TESTING/QGIS_Reference_Data/Scrap/BATCH/reprojectedshapefiles"
   
os.chdir(inpath)
for layers in glob.glob(".shp"):
    outpath = os.path.join(outpath, os.path.basename(layers))
    processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':inpath,'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),'OPERATION':'+proj=noop','OUTPUT':outpath})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While using QGIS processing tool in a script, two parameters are mandatory: the tool name and dictionary-like tool parameters (must be in a dictionary). Therefore, you have to pass the second parameter as dictionary. But you did omit the first (`"INPUT"`) and the fourth (`"OUTPUT"`) tool parameter names.

Briefly, you have to specify the tool parameter names.

```py
import processing
import glob
import os
import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

inpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/QGIS_Scripts_TESTING/QGIS_Reference_Data/Scrap/BATCH/shapefiles"
outpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/QGIS_Scripts_TESTING/QGIS_Reference_Data/Scrap/BATCH/reprojectedshapefiles"

input_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(inpath, "*.shp"))

for input_file in input_files:

    output_file = os.path.join(outpath, os.path.basename(input_file))

    processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {
        'INPUT': input_file, # <- "INPUT"
        'TARGET_CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
        'OPERATION': '+proj=noop',
        'OUTPUT': output_file # <- "OUTPUT"
    })
```

[image]

And you use a folder path for output. It has to be a file path. Use this before `processing.run`:

```py
output_file = os.path.join(outpath, os.path.basename(input_file))
```